# MFC: how to minimize window on button click?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

So its eazy to close via `CDialog::OnOK();` but how to minimize window on costume button click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [CWnd::ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7(v=vs.80).aspx) with `SW_MINIMIZE`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send (post) a WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_MINIMIZE command to the window.